# React Hook Form - Radio buttons with a custom write-in option

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a form in which one of the possible questions that could be asked is a radio button group in which the user could select and write-in their own response to the question.

Example:

[image]

I currently have something like this:

```
const CustomOptionQuestion = (props) => {
    const [otherSelected, setOtherSelected] = useState(false)
    const { formState, register, resetField, trigger } = useFormContext()
    const { isValid, errors } = formState

    // Called when the first three radio buttons are clicked: the "regular" options.
    const onRegularChange = () => {
        setOtherSelected(false) // if we select one of the first three options, unselect the write-in option radio button.

        // Clear out any value in the input field
        resetField("write-in-field")
    }

    // Called when the write-in option radio button is clicked.
    const onOtherSelect = () => {
        setOtherSelected(true)
    }

    return (
        <>
            {props.options.map(option => (
                <input
                    id={option.id}
                    type="radio"
                    value={option.label}
                    {...register("radioWithCustom", {
                        // If the write-in option is selected, then don't require the first three. Otherwise, we'll want one of the first three to be required.
                        required: !otherSelected
                        onChange: onRegularChange
                    })} 
            )}
            {/* Radio button for the write-in option */}
            <input
                checked={otherSelected}
                onChange={onOtherSelect}
                name="radioWithCustom" // Still part of the same radio button group for accessibility purposes.
                type="radio"
            />
            <input 
                disabled={!otherSelected} // Only enable if its associated radio button is clicked.
                error={!isValid}
                {...register('customText', {
                    // Only require inputing in the text field if we've selected the write-in radio button
                    required: { value: otherSelected, message: 'Write a custom option' },
                    minLength: { value: 3, message: 'Input too short' },
                    maxLength: { value: 20, message: 'Input too long' },
                })}
        </>
    )
}
```

Now, this actually works quite well and behaves as it should: A user can only select one of the four radio buttons but if they select the custom one they must type an option.

Notice that I've registered two inputs here: "radioWithCustom" for the radio buttons and "customText" for the text field. The reason why is that they have different `required` properties and different `onChange` behaviors that I would like. If I registered it as the same input, they would clobber each other.

But because I have two inputs registered, my `onSubmit` is not ideal. I get two inputs showing up in my submit data.

```
const MyForm = () => {
    const formMethods = useForm()
    const { handleSubmit } = formMethods

    const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                <CustomOptionQuestion options={/* First three options */} />
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
   
    )
}
```

If selecting a regular option, the `console.log(data)` outputs:

```
{
    radioWithCustom: 'Loyalty'
    customText: undefined
}
```

If selecting a custom option, the `console.log(data)` outputs:

```
{
    radioWithCustom: null
    customText: 'Love' // write-in option
}
```

Now, to my actual question: I would like the output to be of one property regardless of if it's a write-in or regular option

```
{
    radioWithCustom: 'Love' // write-in option but stored here
}
```

Is this possible?